Problem with github actions when creating a test database to run PHPunit in the workflow
I have a project in symfony, and I want to implement CI through github actions, but when running the database tells me an error that the table is already created and therefore can not do the migration, but previously I have forced it to be deleted, I do not understand the error.
I try this .yml
name: Symfony Tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ] 
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  symfony-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_DATABASE: nurses
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        options: >-
          --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping"
          --health-interval=10s
          --health-timeout=5s
          --health-retries=3
    
    steps:
      # Checkout the repository
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      
      # Setup PHP environment
      - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '8.2'  # Ajusta la versión según tus necesidades
          extensions: mbstring, intl, pdo_mysql

      # Copy the .env.test.local file if not already present
      - name: Copy .env.test
        run: php -r "file_exists('.env.test.local') || copy('.env.test', '.env.test.local');"

      # Cache Composer packages
      - name: Cache Composer packages
        id: composer-cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: vendor
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-php-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-php-

      # Install dependencies
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: composer install --no-progress --prefer-dist

      # Wait for MySQL to be ready
      - name: Wait for MySQL to be ready
        run: |
          until mysqladmin ping -h"127.0.0.1" --silent; do
            echo "Waiting for database connection..."
            sleep 1
          done
          
      - name: Drop Database if Exists
        run: php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force --if-exists
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: "mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/nurses"
      
      - name: Create Database
        run: php bin/console doctrine:database:create
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: "mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/nurses"

      - name: Drop Existing Database Schema (force drop all tables)
        run: php bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --force
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: "mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/nurses"
      
      - name: Run Database Migrations
        run: php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: "mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/nurses"

      # Run PHPUnit tests
      - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: "mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/nurses"
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit

And I get this


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

The error message clearly indicates that table "nurses" already exists and I see you've tried using:
doctrine:database:drop --force --if-exists

So you can use a more forceful approach by running an SQL query to remove the table, I'd suggest making a backup of this database before doing so.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nurses;

If this doesn't work perhaps you made an error in the database authentication, double check your credentials and the database variable that you are connecting.
